# CVS Checkout Cron Job

Tags: cron, cvs

I've been researching how to set up a cron job to checkout using cvs with pwd. I don't seem to find the way to do it. The commands I need to run is:

1) cd /listings/2016

2) cvs -d :ext:user@server.com:/usr/local/cvsroot checkout mydir

3) Now I will be prompted for password by the remote server, so I type it and hit enter, then the checkout is performed.

I have tried to login using
cvs -d :pserver:user@server.com:/usr/local/cvsroot/mydir login

So that the password get stored in passwd file, but this option seems to be disabled in the remote server.

I would really like to have all this in a cron job.

Any suggestions. Thanks,

-- Ty